# SQL Show total number duplicate records on each row

Tags: sql, sql-server

I would like to add a column that shows how many other times 'name' appears in other rows. Basically a total number of times that name appears, but listed on each row.

```
select number, name from table;
```

Sample data before addition:

```
number  name     
1234    storeA
1235    storeA
1236    storeA
1237    storeB
1238    storeC
1239    storeC
```

Desired output after addition

```
number  name    Total
1234    storeA  3
1235    storeA  3
1236    storeA  3
1237    storeB  1
1238    storeC  2
1239    storeC  2
```

Comment: Which dbms are you using?

Comment: Tag the DBMS (i.e.`MySQL`, `SQL Server`, etc..) that you are using.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use window function :

```
select t.*,
       count(*) over (partition by name) as total
from table t;
```

However, `ANSI` SQL standard offers correlates subquery approach if window function won't work :

```
select t.*,
       (select count(*)
        from table t1
        where t1.name = t.name
       ) as total
from table t;
```

Comment: I was in the process of writing this very answer when you answered it :)

Comment: Perfect. Thanks!